# Trace event name during dispatch in FLEX

Tags: apache-flex, events, flex3

I'm using FLEX 3.5 and I'd like to trace() something each time a event is being dispatched.
I have 2 types of event, the caingorm event.

For those it's easy, I just need to add this inside the cllass definition :

```
public override function dispatch():Boolean {
    trace("Lancement de l'evenement :", EVENT_ID);
    return super.dispatch();
}
```

However I also have regulars flash.events.Event
which are being dispatched this way :

```
var myEvent:SomeEventType = new SomeEventType ();
Application.application.dispatchEvent(myEvent);
```

How could I trace something like "event : SomeEventType has been dispatched" ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's quite the same if your are tracing the event information from within the function or from before calling the function, in this example. In both examples you will have no guarantee that the event is really dispatched.

Comment: I redefined the dispatch method, if this method is called then then I have the guarantee that the event is really being dispatched.